# How to resize a PNG file from the command line?

Tags: image-manipulation

Suppose I have a image named `1.png` which is currently

```
500px : height
1000px : width
```

I want to resize it to:

```
50px : height
100px : width
```

It must be output in PNG format, not JPG. An example would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Your best bet is Imagemagick

Comment: If the idea is to create thumbnails see http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/ and the various thumbnailer applications (see `apt-cache search thumbnailer` on a Debian-based system for instance).

Answer (score 17):

I'd use `convert` or `mogrify` from the **ImageMagick** suite.

```
$ convert -resize 100x50 1.png 2.png

# or #

$ mogrify -resize 100x50 1.png
```

`convert` takes a separate output filename; creating a separate file.
`mogrify` doesn't take a separate output filename; modifying the file in place

Comment: If you don't know the original size of the photo, but just want to downsize it by 50% in each dimension, how can you do that?

Comment: @BallpointBen: It understands percents: `convert -resize 50%x50% 1.png 2.png`, or just `convert -resize 50% 1.png 2.png`.

Answer (score 6):

The answers you have gotten so far will work in this particular case because your source and target images have the same aspect ratio. However, if you want to change to an arbitrary size, [they will fail](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize):

```
$ file foo.png 
foo.png: PNG image data, 1000 x 500, 8-bit/color RGB, non-interlaced
$ convert -resize 100x50 foo.png bar.png
$ file bar.png 
bar.png: PNG image data, 100 x 50, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

As you can see above, the simple convert works fine when not changing the image's proportions. But what if you want to change them?

```
$ convert -resize 200x50 foo.png bar.png
$ file bar.png 
bar.png: PNG image data, 100 x 50, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

So, when changing the proportions, the command above fails. In order to force `convert` to change an image this way, you need to add a `!` to the end of the geometry specification (and, since `!` is a special character to many shells, you need to escape it as `\!`):

```
$ convert -resize 200x50\! foo.png bar.png
$ file bar.png 
bar.png: PNG image data, 200 x 50, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Imagemagick for this.

Read the man page for correct use but it should work by passing parameters, something like

`convert 1.png -resize 50x100 1-resized.png`

Comment: At least on Debian, the man pages for ImageMagick tools are useless (except at pointing out where to find the real information like file:///usr/share/doc/imagemagick/www/convert.html or http://www.imagemagick.org/script/convert.php (though that latter one might be for a different version of ImageMagick)).

Comment: The geometry argument is actually (in it's simplest form) "widthxheight", so it should be  -resize 100x50

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to ImageMagick is the venerable netpbm:

```
pngtopnm input.png | pnmscale -reduce 10 | pnmtopng > output.png
```

Comment: Is `pngtopnm` really well known/respected? This is the first I've heard of it.